# C#, как происходит возвращение значимого типа из метода на уровне памяти(stack)

Tags: c#, методы, return, стек, frame

В книге Рихтера наткнулся на следующее строки:
"Повторюсь: для метода, возвращающего значимый тип, поля экземпляра копируются в память,выделенную вызывающим кодом в месте возврата из метода, что снижает эффективность работы программы."

```
public static void Main()
{
    MyStruct myStruct = new MyStruct();
    double result = myStruct.RadiusVector(3);
}
struct MyStruct
{
    double x = 9;
    public double RadiusVector(double z)
    {
        double y = z * 2;
        return Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
    }
}
```

На примере этого кода хотелось бы узнать: что именно скопируется в память, выделенную вызывающим кодом в месте возврата из метода и как весь этот код будет лежать в стеке?
(если я правильно понял, то после отработки метода RadiusVector в стеке, во фрейме метода Main будут лежать три переменные: x, y и result каждая по 8 байт? поправьте меня)

Comment: Зачем коду лежать в стеке? Стек для данных предназначен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После возврата из метода в стеке будет лежать две переменные `myStruct` 8 байт и `result` 8 байт, но это не точно. Код не лежит в стеке никогда, код лежит в кеше процессора и выполняется.

К примеру, у вас 64-битное приложение, тогда первые 3 аргумента не кладутся в стек вообще, а передаются через регистры процессора. Логически весь код будет работать со стеком так:

```
0 пустой стек
8 push myStruct
16 call RadiusVector (push текущий адрес возврата)
24 push y
здесь математика
16 rsp-8 (очистка стека RadiusVector)
8 ret (pop текущий адрес возврата)
16 push result
```

Но это если код не оптимизирован.

Давайте посмотрим на оптимизированный код, я только ваш код переписал так, чтобы он комиилировался.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        MyStruct myStruct = new MyStruct(9);
        double result = myStruct.RadiusVector(3);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}

struct MyStruct
{
    double x;
    
    public MyStruct(double x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
    
    public double RadiusVector(double z)
    {
        double y = z * 2;
        return Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
    }
}
```

А вот во что он компилируется

```
Program.Main()
    L0000: sub rsp, 0x28 ; выделить 28 байт в стеке
    L0004: vzeroupper
    L0007: vmovsd xmm0, [0x7ff9052d0488]
    L000f: vmovsd [rsp+0x20], xmm0
    L0015: vmovsd xmm1, [rsp+0x20]
    L001b: vmulsd xmm1, xmm1, xmm1
    L001f: vaddsd xmm1, xmm1, [0x7ff9052d0490]
    L0027: vaddsd xmm0, xmm1, xmm0
    L002b: vsqrtsd xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
    L002f: call 0x00007ff8fc64f840 ; Console.WriteLine
    L0034: nop
    L0035: add rsp, 0x28 ; очистить 28 байт в стеке
    L0039: ret

MyStruct..ctor(Double)
    L0000: vzeroupper
    L0003: vmovsd [rcx], xmm1 ; this.x = x;
    L0007: ret

MyStruct.RadiusVector(Double)
    L0000: vzeroupper
    L0003: vaddsd xmm0, xmm1, xmm1 ; z + z
    L0007: vmovsd xmm2, [rcx] ; xmm2 = this.x;
    L000b: vmulsd xmm2, xmm2, xmm2 ; x * x
    L000f: vmulsd xmm0, xmm0, xmm0 ; y * y
    L0013: vaddsd xmm0, xmm2, xmm0 ; + 
    L0017: vmulsd xmm1, xmm1, xmm1 ; z * z
    L001b: vaddsd xmm0, xmm0, xmm1 ; +
    L001f: vsqrtsd xmm0, xmm0, xmm0 ; Math.Sqrt
    L0023: ret
```

В ассемблере `;` - это коммертарий, если что. `xmm*` регистры процессора типа `double`. `rsp` - адрес стека. `rcx` - регистр общего назначения. Еще по конвенции fastcall для x64 приложений, первый аргумент метода с плавающей точкой передается через xmm1, а возвращаемое значение - через xmm0.

Обратите внимание, JIT компилятор вообще заинлайнил код метода RadiusVector внутрь Main. Стек вообще не используется.

Кстати вот это использование стека

```
    L000f: vmovsd [rsp+0x20], xmm0
    L0015: vmovsd xmm1, [rsp+0x20]
```

Но выглядит как баг компилятора, точнее не баг, а недостаточная оптимизация, так как эти 2 инструкции легко заменить на одну

```
    L000f: vmovsd xmm1, xmm0
```

Если без этой оптимизации, то в стеке всего 8 байт данных, если с оптимизацией, то 0.

Отсюда вывод. Ничего общего на настоящимой момент между содержимым книжки и реальности я не вижу. Не верьте всему, что пишут, везде есть нюансы.