# Как происходит инициализация переменных в C# и где они "лежат" перед созданием?

Tags: c#

Есть несколько переменных:

```
var a = 1;
var b = "string";
var c = false;
var d = new MyClass();
```

Можете объяснить, где лежат значения этих переменных перед их инициализацией?

Правильно ли я понимаю, что на этапе компиляции значения помещаются в кучу, а в рантайме из кучи берутся значения?

Comment: На этапе компиляции нет никакой кучи. На этапе компиляции генерятся инструкции в виде байт-кода. Во время выполнения да, видимо при исполнении рантайма инициализируется куча и когда доходит дело до этих строк, то сам объект создаётся в куче, а в переменную помещается ссылка на него.

Comment: _этих переменных перед их инициализацией_ - вы показали в коде 4 проинициализированные значениями переменные. Что значит "перед инициализацией"? Где лежит код их создающий или что? Код лежит там же где и всё остальное приложение - в памяти, оттуда части кода попадают в кеш процессора и там выполняются, грубо говоря.

Comment: От себя добавлю: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1329097/184217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Глобально память можно поделить на 2 области: **стек** и **куча**.

Размер **стека** всегда известен и фиксирован ещё на этапе компиляции внутри конкретного блока кода. В нём хранятся переменные локальной области видимости

В куче же хранятся данные, размер которых (на этапе компиляции) не известен.

*Я немного всё упрощу для понимания, но основные концепции понять можно*

Давайте не основе примера разберём, как именно выделяется память. Допустим у нас есть блок кода:

```cs
{
  int x;
  string str = "Hello world!";
  List<int> intList = new() {1, 2, 3};
  MyClass anyClass = new();
  MyStruct anyStruct = new();
}
```

Представим **стек** как массив байт: `[...]`. Когда мы открываем новый блок кода мы грубо говоря объявляем, что сейчас в стеке будет использовано ещё `N` байтов. Для этого нам заранее (ещё на этапе компиляции) должен быть известен размер данного блока кода.

Однако не все типы фиксированного размера. Типы, размер которых неизвестен на этапе компиляции лежат в куче. Таким образом в C# появляется **разделение на [ссылочные типы](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) и [типы значений](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types)**

Размер типов значений нам известен на этапе компиляции. Для `int` это например 4 байта.

Ссылочные же типы превращаются в **значение адреса в памяти самого объекта**, т. е. в `nint` (тип, размер которого зависит от разрядности системы). Сам объект же лежит в куче, и при обращении к нему мы его достаём из него.

*P. S.: Для упрощения представим, что тип строки представляет из себя ссылочный тип, так как там свои тонкости.*

В связи с этой информацией перепишем код выше на идентичный, но более близкий к компилятору:

```cs
{
  int x;
  nint strPointer;
  nint listPoiner;
  nint classPointer;
  MyStruct anyStruct; // Структуры являются типом значений
}
```

Теперь мы можем вычислить размер данного блока кода сложив размеры всех локальных полей (для этого можно использовать встроенную функцию `sizeof(T)`, но для ссылочных типов оно возвращает размер самого объекта, а не его ссылки):

```
int32 (4 байта) + 
int64(8 байтов) +
int64(8 байтов) +
int64(8 байтов) + 
MyStruct (сумма размеров всех полей, допустим 4 * 3 байта) =
40 байтов
```

Теперь на стеке в том же порядке мы выделяем эти 40 байтов под наши типы:

`[..., int32_0, int32_1, int32_2, int32_3, int64_0, int64_1, ...]`

Что бы получить доступ к переменной x нам надо получить `sizeof(int)` (4) байтов со сдвигом 0 относительно текущего блока кода.

Что бы получить доступ к ссылке на строку нам надо получить `sizeof(int64)` (8) байтов со сдвигом суммы всех предыдущих размеров (`sizeof(int)` байтов, так как перед ним стоит только int)

Что бы получить доступ к данным `anyStruct` переменной, нам надо получить `sizeof(MyStruct)` (12) байтов со сдвигом `sizeof(int) + sizeof(int64) + sizeof(int64) + sizeof(int64)` (28) байтов

Т. е. грубо говоря для данного блока кода относительно его начала внутри стека стек всегда будет выглядеть так:
`[..., int, int64, int64, int64, MyStruct, ...]`

**Отвечая на главный вопрос:**

Перед инициализацией они лежат в стеке, и C# по умолчанию присваивает им значения по умолчанию.

Если же говорить про объекты, то до инициализации в куче они могут вообще не существовать (`null` значит нулевая ссылка, т. е. на ничто)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1481746/373567, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1365380/373567, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1395240/373567 почитать

Comment: _Перед инициализацией они лежат в стеке_ - нигде они не лежат. Их просто нет. На низком уровне нет понятия переменной, есть только понятие значения. Нет значения - значит нет ничего. Это важно.

Comment: @aepot Ну это уже спор о терминологии. В моём контексте это работает так: *переменная лежит там, где лежит (или будет лежать) её значение*. Если представлять переменную как контейнер размером с размер этой самой переменной (что и происходит на уровне языка), то данное определение более чем подходит. Нам известно где *лежит* переменная когда (грубо говоря) начинается определённый блок с локальными переменными, ведь нам известно, где лежит или будет лежать её значение. А так как значение в ней всегда есть (не существует несуществующего значения), то и переменная после объявления блока там лежит

Comment: Это не спор о терминологии, это указание на то, что в этом ответе есть утверждения, способные ввести читателя ответа в заблуждение. Начинаете рассказывать про распределение памяти, а затем выясняется, что это не физическая память, а абстракция, в которой живут сущности языкового уровня. Как в этом не запутаться?

Comment: _представим, что тип строки представляет из себя ссылочный тип_ - а тип строки не является ссылочным типом?

Comment: @Grundy Признаю, ошибся. Вначале почему то подумал, что строка чуть более сложный тип, что то типа структуры с ссылкой на само содержание строки (хотя возможно всё и вправду так, просто я не нашёл), однако официально строка всё же ссылочный тип

Comment: Попробуйте переосмыслить и доработать ответ так, чтобы он стал понятнее будущим посетителям. В нём есть лишнее, некоторые двояко читаемые утверждения можно просто убрать без ущерба содержимому ответа.

Comment: `Перед инициализацией они лежат в стеке - нигде они не лежат` - ну чего докопались до мелочи?  по сути верно, только чуть правильнее будет сказать "перед инициализацией переменных в стеке уже зарезервировано конкретное место, где будут лежать их значения или указатели на их значения, а инициализация заносит туда эти значения"